# posting italics to twitter with Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, twitter, unicode

I am using Net::Twitter::Lite and I want to post text with parts in italics. I learned that this is possible with Unicode: http://mothereff.in/twitalics There is Java-Script code, but I do not understand it. Is there some Perl code that does the same? Or can somebody explain what the JavaScript does so that I can do the same in Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This program will convert a string of characters into italics, using the Unicode characters for mathematical symbols.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CS

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use charnames ':full';

my $out;
foreach (@ARGV) {
  foreach my $char (split //) {
    if ($char =~ /[A-Z]/) {
      my $charname = "MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL $char";
      $char = charnames::string_vianame $charname;
    } elsif ($char =~ /[a-z]/) {
      my $charname = 'MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL ' . uc $char;
      $char = charnames::string_vianame $charname;
    }
    $out .= $char;
  }
}
say $out;
```

Comment: Thanks! My Perl complains: Can't locate object method "string_vianame" via package "charnames" at utf-italics.pl line 17.

Comment: Looks like that function was added in Perl 5.14. See https://metacpan.org/module/JESSE/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#N-NAME-and-charnames-enhancements

Comment: I now have a working Perl and get italics, however, my Perl 5.16 seems to dislike "h": It says: `Use of uninitialized value $char in concatenation (.) or string at utf-test.pl line 19.`

Comment: Apparently 'MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL H' doesn't exist because it would be the same glyph as 'PLANCK CONSTANT'. So you'll need to write a special case for that.

Comment: Or you can add an alias: `use charnames ":alias" => {"MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL H" => "PLANCK CONSTANT" };`

Comment: Hm. I tried the latter suggestion, but now Perl is unhappy with all letters. I just inserted the line after the first `use charnames`.

Comment: This works: `use charnames ':full', ':alias' => {"MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL H" => "PLANCK CONSTANT" };`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old version of Perl, you can use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

$output="";
foreach (@ARGV)
{
 foreach $char (split //)
 {
  if ($char =~ /[A-Z]/) {$d=119860-65+ord($char); $char = pack("U",$d)}
  if ($char =~ /h/) {$char="\x{210e}"}
  if ($char =~ /[a-z]/) {$d=119886-97+ord($char); $char = pack("U",$d)}
  $output .= $char;
 }
}

print "$output\n";
```